# When sum() a column I get this error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sum'

Tags: sum, pyspark, word-count

I have a dataframe like this:

```
+-----+--------+
|count| country|
+-----+--------+
|   12| Ireland|
|    5|Thailand|
+-----+--------+
```

when I add  sum() function to get the total of the first column 'count' I get this error :

```
 AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

I do import the `from pyspark.sql.functions import sum`

How do I sum or what am I missing?

Thank you and appreciate any help.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import sum
>>> a = [(12,"Ireland"),(5,"Thailand")]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(a,["count","country"])
>>> df.show()
+-----+--------+
|count| country|
+-----+--------+
|   12| Ireland|
|    5|Thailand|
+-----+--------+
```

As you can see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy):

> **groupBy()**: Groups the DataFrame using the specified columns, so we can run aggregation on them. See GroupedData for all the available aggregate functions.

In [GroupedData](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData) you can find a set of methods for aggregations on a DataFrame, such as **sum()**, **avg()** ,**mean()**.

So you have to group your data before applying these functions.

```
>>> total = df.groupBy().sum()
>>> total.show()
+----------+
|sum(count)|
+----------+
|        17|
+----------+
```

See [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.sum) for an example with **sum()**